# Can you add a person to watch a JIRA issue?

Tags: jira

In some cases, I'd like to let a teammate watch an issue, and be informed of whatever is going on about that issue, even though the issue is not assigned to him/her.

Is it possible to add a person to watch an exising issue, without assigning the task to him/her?

How?

Comment: I have permission to Add Watchers, but it says that user does not exist. If admin try to add user to watcher, than there is no problem.

Comment: If you have a question, then post it as a separate question, not as an answer. You may reference this question if you like.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12786)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a person to watch an exising issue, without assigning the task to him/her?

Absolutely, this is documented within [Watching and Voting on an Issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Watching+and+Voting+on+an+Issue):

> If you have the correct [permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Watching+and+Voting+on+an+Issue#WatchingandVotingonanIssue-permissions) (see below), you can also
>   view the voter and watcher lists for an issue and, **you can manage the
>   watcher list — that is, add other people to the watcher list**. This is
>   useful if you need to draw someone's attention to a particular issue. *[emphasis mine]*

The relevant [permission](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Watching+and+Voting+on+an+Issue#WatchingandVotingonanIssue-permissions) is:

- **Manage Watcher List** — permits a user to view/edit the watcher list.

You can manage the list by clicking on the watcher count icon:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer and completely correct!

Comment: This feature has arrived with the latest update (that we started using this September). It was a missing feature. FYI. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have added people as a watcher on particular tickets that I thought they would be interested in. You will have to add a 3rd Party plug in to do this - works fine. Check out - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Add+watchers+in+the+Issue+creation+screen

Comment: I'm not an admin, and we do not have the possibility for add-ons at the company. Still, useful answer.

Comment: While this 3rd party plugin is still the only way to add watchers during creation of _new_ issues (+1), managing watchers for _existing_ issues is available out of the box, see my  [separate answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/15633/177) for details.